# Google Sheets - use API to get list of gid in a workbook

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-workspace, tableofcontents

I have a Google Sheets workbook which has approx 50 sheets in it.

I would like to create a Table of Contents (TOC)/Index sheet which lists all the sheets and provides a hyperlink to the sheets for easy access.

Ideally the TOC is dynamically updated so no manual intervention is required.

I have this in the code to return a list of all the sheets in the workbook:

```
function sheetnames() {
    var out = new Array()
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
    return out 
}
```

This all works, however I need to be able to identify the GIDs of the individual tabs/sheets and that's where I am struggling. I need the GIDs to create the hyperlink to the sheets themselves so that the process is automated and there is less chance of making a mistake by manually making alterations.

Has anyone managed to do this? I would have thought it would be a simple request but G Suite support pointed me here.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Does this help? [How could I get the link of an specific sheet with Google script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664508/how-could-i-get-the-link-of-an-specific-sheet-with-google-script)

Comment: Use the relevant class method of the `Sheet` object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got the sheet names, add the following custom function to your Apps Script for the spreadsheet:

```
function GID(worksheet_name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(worksheet_name);
  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  return gid;
}
```

Then you can just run the custom function in a column next to where you have the column of worksheet names. So if there's a worksheet name in A2, in B2 you can input `=GID(A2)` and that will output the worksheet's GID in B2.